# ML Engine models takes large time for online prediction

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, object-detection-api

Hi I have an object detection model in Cloud ML Engine.I am in India and the region available for online prediction is asia-northeast1.I did set up a node server in AWS for uploading the pics to ML engine model.The result response takes more than 60 seconds.Where have I gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

CloudML Engine by default serves using a single CPU which is very slow for object detection. We continue to expand our hardware offering. Please reach out to cloudml-feedback@google.com to gain access to more appropriate machines (in alpha).

Comment: I have mailed them,but no response.Can you suggest me the hardware requirement.